# php click link to show map based on sent id through jquery post()

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, post

result of my post() only show data generated of other map.php but its unable to show map box. i am sending id through post() and it show the exact php data from mysql database. only map div is emptry. following is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mylink").click(function(){
        var $linkattr = $(this).attr("rel");
//      alert($linkattr);
        $.post("map.php", {myid:$linkattr}).done(function(data) {
            $("#mapcomeshere").html(data);
            evt.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

my map.php script is

```
<?php
include('db.php');

$myid = "25";//$_POST['myid'];
$result = mysql_query("select * from property Where Id = '" . $myid ."' AND status = 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['Id'] . " : " . $row['owner'] . " : " . $row['lnglat'] . $row['propertyadd']  ."<br>";

$maploc = $row['lnglat'];
$myadd = $row['propertyadd'];
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 13,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.893379,67.028061),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    var onMarkerClick = function() {
      var marker = this;
      var latLng = marker.getPosition();
      infoWindow.setContent('<?php echo $myadd ?>');

      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    };
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
      infoWindow.close();
    });

    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $maploc ?>)
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', onMarkerClick);
  });
</script>
hi
<div id="map"></div>
```

please help

Comment: `evt.preventDefault();` is in wrong place and `evt` is undefined so will throw error. Always check browser console for errors

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things I can suggest.

Firstly, you have a conceptual problem in your code, where you write:

```
  infoWindow.setContent('<?php echo $myadd ?>');
```

You need to understand that PHP is handled on the server, and as such, it cannot be directly executed by JavaScript in this way.  What this will do, is literally change the content of the infoWindow to '<?php echo $myadd ?>'.

Now as for your question, I think you are going about it the wrong way by returning all that code over the AJAX response.  The JavaScript should live in the page, and only the data should be returned by map.php, probably in the form of JSON data, for example:

map.php:

```
// ... database stuff, then finally:
echo json_encode(array(
    'map' => array(
        'lat' => 67.028061,
        'long' => 24.893379,
        'zoom' => 13
    ),
    'infoWindowContent' => $myadd,
    //... etc
));
```

The rest of that JavaScript belongs in the callback to $.post().

```
    $.post("map.php", {myid:$linkattr}).done(function(data) {
        // Not this: $("#mapcomeshere").html(data);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), data.map);
            // ... setup event handlers, etc ...
        });
    });
```

What this does is provide a cleaner API for your code.  The responsibility of map.php is only to provide the data for the map, not the JavaScript.  The JavaScript is all in one place.

Comment: infoWindow.setContent('<?php echo $myadd ?>'); will set the content to value of $myadd!

Comment: Yeah you're right.  I misread it.  The rest of my answer still stands though, this isn't the way to do it.

Comment: There also needs to be a `dataType: "json"` in there somewhere.

Comment: following code works perfectly where i want to place dynamic marker with address detail
$myid = "25";
//$myid = $_POST['myid'];
$result = mysql_query("select * from property Where Id = '" . $myid ."' AND status = 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['Id'] . " : " . $row['owner'] . " : " . $row['lnglat'] . $row['propertyadd']  ."<br>";
$maploc = $row['lnglat'];
$myadd = $row['propertyadd'];